# Return value of get_permalink(0) and get_the_title(0)

Tags: permalinks, child-pages

I'm new to wordpress and I'm following a tutorial right now but I don't understand wordpresses behaviour. I'm trying to change the title of a sidebar which lists the parentpage and it's childpages, this works fine but I don't understand why  `$parentID = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID()); echo get_permalink($parentID);` works even on the parent page, I echoed the result on the parent page and it returns 0 since the parent page doesnt have a parent, so why does this still work? Why does `get_permalink(0)` get me to the parent page if I press the button on the parent page? It also gives me the Title even though it would be `get_the_title(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an ID is passed to `get_the_title()` or `get_permalink()`, they will use `get_post()` internally to get a copy of the full post object with that ID. But if `get_post()` is passed either nothing or a ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like `0`, then it will return the current global `$post` object. In the context of your code this is *likely* to be the current page.

So:

```
get_permalink( 0 );
```

Is equivalent to:

```
get_permalink( get_the_ID() );
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
get_permalink();
```

Because they are all referring to the current `global $post`.